# Is there a common name for pop-up damage numbers, such as in RPGs?

Tags: terminology

It just occurred to me that I've never heard a name for the damage numbers that pop up over characters, typically in RPGs.  After some searching I found one person call them "poppers", but no other names.

[image]

Is there a name, perhaps used inside the gaming industry, for these numbers?

Comment: [Relevant Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/do-we-want-to-support-is-there-a-term-for-x-questions)

Comment: Voting to reopen as per community consensus at: [Do we want to change our policy on “Is There a Term for X?” questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15942/4797)

Answer (score 9):

Two different names I have commonly heard used are [Combat text](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_Text) or [damage text](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Multiplayer_options). Both are used fairly frequently and are interchangeable, though in my personal experience, I have heard damage text used more frequently. See links for examples of use in games. Combat text generally also includes things like status effects as well. Damage text is just "damage numbers", which as @badp mentioned is another phrase that can be used.

Comment: Would "combat text" include status effects and the like?

Comment: also "damage numbers"

Comment: @DCShannon most of the time I've seen it used, it refers to status effect text as well.

Comment: @badp Damage numbers sounds right. I would definitely know what you meant. Not just the damage, but the *numbers*.

Comment: Sometimes damage indicators

Answer (score 7):

Generalized, the term I see and hear the most for these kinds of things is "floating" text.  It can be more specific:  Dragonrage's answer mentions combat text or damage text, but it isn't restricted to a combat scenario.  Floating text is often used to contextualize numbers or short phrases by causing it to float near whatever it's meant to represent - damage floats off of or pops off of the damaged creature or character (or their hp bar); gained resources appear as +1's near your stock of that resource, the places you collected or delivered it, or both; a reminder on which button digs for treasure could rise from the earth as your character nears the big X on the ground.

Sometimes I think the floating text that "pops" up and then falls away should be called something else, since it doesn't exactly "float", but typically I still hear it called floating text, or it's replaced with a more specialized term like "damage indicator" or "pop-up reminder".